# Что означает запись $.function в javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Что означает запись $.function в javascript?
Пример:

```
$.createPassword("Password1Base", "Element", {
Constructor: function(params) {
    //тело конструктора
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте разбирать [$ - это псевдоним](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667736/what-does-the-sign-mean-in-jquery-or-javascript/8667760#:%7E:text=In%20jQuery%2C%20the%20%24%20sign%20is,an%20alias%20to%20a%20function.&text=The%20jQuery%20syntax%20is%20tailor,on%20the%20element(s).&text=The%20%24%20symbol%20simply%20invokes%20the%20jQuery%20library%27s%20selector%20functionality.) для `jQuery()`

Допустим что есть такой код

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.createPassword = function( passBase, element, object) {
      .....
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );
```

Это расширение библиотеки `jQuery` методом `createPassword`. По виду типичный [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) с параметром `jQuery`

Соответственно "Password1Base", "Element", { Constructor: function(params) ...} в

```
$.createPassword("Password1Base", "Element", {
Constructor: function(params) {
    //тело конструктора
  }
}
```

это параметры вызова `$.createPassword` расширения `jQuery`

Comment: вообще не только для jQuery - в принципе это может быть что угодно, в том числе и браузерное апи

Comment: @Grundy конечно, может быть что угодно. Но в данном случае метка jQuery. Я конечно предполагаю код 
и пишу опираясь от этого.

Comment: Да, пропустил метку

Answer (score 1):

Обычно под `$` в JS понимается JQuery, но на самом деле это alias (псевдоним) для импорта.

```
import * as $ from 'https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery';
```

Данная строка подразумевает, что необходимо импортировать все модули `*` под именем `$` из источника `https://cdn.skypack.dev/jquery`. Вместо `$` можно дать другое имя, например `jquery`.

Однако из контекста вопроса невозомжно понять, какая именно библиотека скрывается под именем `$`.

Comment: У меня есть код страницы, содержащей множество таких функций с различными входными параметрами. Т.е.                                                                                          $.createPassword("Password1Base", "Element", {
Constructor: function(params) {
    //тело конструктора
  }
}$.createPassword("Password1Base", "Form", {
Constructor: function(params) {
    //тело конструктора
  }
} $.createPassword("Password1Base", "Object", {
Constructor: function(params) {
    //тело конструктора
  }
} Я не понимаю что означает подобная перегрузка вкупе с $.function

Comment: ну под $ скорее всего скрывается библиотека и скорее всего это jquery

Comment: В Js ytn перегрузок функций они тупо перезаписываются. Так что ваш метод в различным вызовом по сути одна функция.

Comment: а с чего вдруг _на самом деле это alias (псевдоним) для импорта_? Может в коде вообще импорты не использовались